# jQuery selector not selecting object

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some HTML.

```
<td class="qDescription">
    <div>
         <div id="questionTitle">% of users who logged in per day</div>
         <div id="timeRangeExt"> 05 Mar 2015 - 11 Mar 2015</div>
         <div class="compareToLabel"> (26 Feb 2015 - 04 Mar 2015)</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I'm trying to change the CSS property of `#timeRangeExt`, so I have the following jQuery:

```
$("#timeRangeExt").html("TESTING");
```

However, it doesn't work. I'm really at a loss here. I've done this 1000 times before, but this time it just won't select.

Comment: Have you checked the ID you're trying to select? You're missing the "Ext" part on the end.

Comment: Ya sorry, I edited that. Actually have 2 different IDs, so I mixed them up. To clarify, its still broken.

Comment: Are you doing this before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: `$(function() { $("#timeRangeExt").html("TESTING"); })`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it seems to work fine.... http://jsfiddle.net/ph3twmbc/

Comment: Errors in the console?

Comment: @Scimonster Yup, turns out I was! Though doing it after it was loaded was equally fruitless. So I ended up just calculating the CSS I wanted and passed it to the object as I was constructing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Need to reference the complete id (`#timeRangeExt`):</strike>

```
$('#timeRangeExt').css('color','#f0f');
```

It appears it was a typo. If you have two IDs with the same value (if `qDescription` is a repeated element) you're going to have to use a class name instead. HTML *cannot* have two IDs with the same name on a single document. For example, switch it up to:

```
<td class="qDescription">
    <div>
         <div class="questionTitle">% of users who logged in per day</div>
         <div class="timeRangeExt"> 05 Mar 2015 - 11 Mar 2015</div>
         <div class="compareToLabel"> (26 Feb 2015 - 04 Mar 2015)</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Then you can select it in reference to `.qDescription`:

```
$('.qDescription .timeRangeExt').css('color','#f0f');
```

Another options is, if it's dynamically laid out, is to add an incrementing value (e.g. `el.id = 'timeRangeExt' + increment;`) then, of course, reference it by its new id (`$('#timeRangeExt2').css(...)`).

Comment: This seems to have been a typo in the question.

Comment: Ya sorry, I edited that. Actually have 2 different IDs, so I mixed them up. To clarify, its still broken.

Comment: If you still can't select it, check you don't have two IDs with the same value. DOM doesn't support it, and browser is probably only picking up on the first instance.

Comment: I do have 2 IDs of the same value. I swear I've done it before, will it work with classes? But for the record, it isn't changing the first one either.

Comment: + wait for the page to be loaded `$(function(){ /* code here */ });`

Comment: @Jake Yes it will work with classes if you use a jQuery class selector

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle :D. I'm still trying to figure out why my selector is reponding with undefined.

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your code and it should be like

```
$("#timeRangeExt").html("TESTING");
```